# How to set currentItemView as per user selection on load of iCarousel CoverflowViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coverflow, icarousel

I'm having a RootViewController in which I have a UITableViewController on click of this table cell I will enter in to CoverflowViewController, here I'm having an array of elements so I'm setting NUMBER_OF_ITEMS to [myArray count];
and viewForItemAtIndex: method I'm just iterating array objects and assigning the text to the view. Everything is working fine up to here.

Now on each load the currentItemView is 0th index element of my array but I need to make my currentItemView as dynamic (say, 5th element of my array on load) depending on previous RootViewController tableView Selection. Since currentItemView is a readOnly property I'm not able to assign value to it also, so how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: firstly on selection of 5 th how many items you want to show on carousel? only 5 th item or 5 th item as a middle item??

Comment: i got answer for my own question we need to use **scrollToItemAtIndex:animated** property of iCarousel.